# Change XAML Margin in universal app based on resolution

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Universal app for Wp8.1/WinRt.

For the phone, I have a gridview that displays grids containing stackpanels as 'ItemTemplate'.

The grids have margins specified explicitly, like so:

```
 <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentItems}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Grid Width="140" Margin="6,0,6,6" x:Name="I_WANT_TO_ADJUST_MY_MARGINS">
                      <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                        <Grid Height="140" Width="140">
                        <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" Opacity="0.6"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayedName}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Margin="3" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
  </GridView>
```

This looks great on a 6" inch phone giving me a 3 column look. But on a small phone, while I get two columns, the amount of negative space on the right is horrible.

I want to be able to make the margins of the grid **I_WANT_TO_ADJUST_MY_MARGINS** bigger if the screen is smaller?

Note: This layout is specifically for running on the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

1. Add two datatemplates (big/small screen) to a resources dictionary - I used the page resources, but you can probably use any.
2. Add a DataTemplateSelector to the page resources. Specify the above two templates as properties, like so:

   `<local:WpDataTemplateSelector x:Key="WpDataTemplateSelector" BigScreenTemplate="{StaticResource BigScreen}" SmallScreenTemplate="{StaticResource SmallScreen}"></converters:WpDataTemplateSelector>`
3. In the DataTemplateSelector use the following to determine screen width:`Window.Current.Bounds.Width`
4. Specify the **ItemTemplateSelector** property on the GridView